# Transparent form with background image

Tags: c#, background, transparency, backcolor

I am trying to set the form's background as invisible as I want the background image to be the thing that has the transparency.

I have used multiple background colours; - lime, magenta, red, white with the same transparency key but they all give me a horrible **[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/thXUA.png)**. You can see that I have set the backcolour to be yellow, and the transparency key to yellow but at the top there is still yellow

I have also used

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

That didn't work either and neither did

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e) { /* Ignore */ }
```

Does anyone have a way that I can do this?

Comment: You want the background picture to be transparent by any percentage?

Comment: No, I need the form to be invisible so it's just the background picture and buttons visible (see in image, I need the yellow gone)

Comment: as far as I know it is not possible with transparency. You'll need to create graphics

Comment: I have a background image that has transparency, I have tried removing the background image from the form, then adding a picture box but that didn't work either

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.clip.aspx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4387680/transparent-background-on-winforms

Comment: Non of those solutions in the link worked (stackflow link)..

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/e0y1vbn.png . This is what I want the form to look like, the squares are the transparency

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3780779/transparent-or-semitransparent-panel-control

Comment: I have already tried those, still give me the same result (only partially gone)