# clipping rectangle form winform as image

Tags: c#, winforms

I have Picturebox with 3 labels above it, the labels are changed according to row selected from table. when i try to export the Picturebox (with the labels above it) as image the resulted image contains only the background, and the labels are disappeared

this is my code for clipping

```
using (Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap(pictureBox1.Image))
            {
                var newImg = bmp.Clone(new System.Drawing.Rectangle { X = 0, Y = 0, Width = bmp.Width, Height = bmp.Height  },bmp.PixelFormat);
                pictureBox2.Image = newImg;
            }
```

who can i add the labels to newImg ??

Comment: [Control.DrawToBitmap](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.drawtobitmap). Use the PictureBox ClientSize/ClientRectangle for the Bitmap's dimensions.

Comment: Put the 3 `Label`-s and the `PictureBox` in a `Panel` and use the `DrawToBitmap` method of that `Panel`

Comment: both of the ways are return the picturebox background only

Comment: _both of the ways are return the picturebox background only_ No, they will work just fine if the Labels are __nested__ in the PBox, not just sitting above it. (`label1.Parent=pictureBox1;label1.Location=...`). Show the new code! Note that there is a [quirk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24592272/creating-semi-transparent-panels-controls-is-there-a-foolproof-way/24597214#24597214) with that function, though if the Labels are overlapping; this bug will also bite if doing it like JQSOFT said. - Not that instead of Lables you could use pbox.Paint and TextRenderer..

Comment: You can also add the label Controls to the `PictureBox.Controls` collection: `pictureBox1,Controls.Add(theLabel) theLabel.BringToFront();`. Of course, you have to relocate the Label, since it's Parent is now changed and it's old Location was relative to the previous Parent. As TaW informed you, overlapping Controls won't render well. You can nest Controls (a Label inside a semi/transparent Panel, for example) and maintain transparency/translucency. Otherwise, paint the text on the PictureBox surface or on a Bitmap. That will give you the best results and avoid the *quirks*.

Comment: i tied it, all the labels are placed inside panel and i put my image in panel's background it's worked, so thanks a lot.