# Making a control transparent

Tags: c#, winforms

I am currently developing a simple image editing tool using *Winforms* and `.NET 3.5` (work environment).

I have a requirement that when the user clicks a select tool button, a square (rectangle in C#) will appear that they can scale between `100x100` and `400x400`. I have this bit fixed - the issue comes with making the background of the rectangle transparent.

I'm a little unclear on if transparency is supported in `.NET 3.5`, I've tried the following:

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
pnlSelectArea.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
pnlSelectArea.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;
selectArea1.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
selectArea1.ForeColor = Color.Transparent;
```

But this has no effect - any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/72994/net-windows-forms-transparent-control

Comment: Thanks for the help - I can't apply any of this to my solution but I appreciate the effort.

Comment: You can find my simple approach explained in the post [here:](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34404064/1529012)

Answer (score 56, accepted):

This is my special Control which contains an opacity property, it 100% works:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.ComponentModel.Design;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Windows.Forms.Design;

public class TranspCtrl : Control
{
    public bool drag = false;
    public bool enab = false;
    private int m_opacity = 100;

    private int alpha;
    public TranspCtrl()
    {
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
        SetStyle(ControlStyles.Opaque, true);
        this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
    }

    public int Opacity
    {
        get
        {
            if (m_opacity > 100)
            {
                m_opacity = 100;
            }
            else if (m_opacity < 1)
            {
                m_opacity = 1;
            }
            return this.m_opacity;
        }
        set
        {
            this.m_opacity = value;
            if (this.Parent != null)
            {
                Parent.Invalidate(this.Bounds, true);
            }
        }
    }

    protected override CreateParams CreateParams
    {
        get
        {
            CreateParams cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle = cp.ExStyle | 0x20;
            return cp;
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        Graphics g = e.Graphics;
        Rectangle bounds = new Rectangle(0, 0, this.Width - 1, this.Height - 1);

        Color frmColor = this.Parent.BackColor;
        Brush bckColor = default(Brush);

        alpha = (m_opacity * 255) / 100;

        if (drag)
        {
            Color dragBckColor = default(Color);

            if (BackColor != Color.Transparent)
            {
                int Rb = BackColor.R * alpha / 255 + frmColor.R * (255 - alpha) / 255;
                int Gb = BackColor.G * alpha / 255 + frmColor.G * (255 - alpha) / 255;
                int Bb = BackColor.B * alpha / 255 + frmColor.B * (255 - alpha) / 255;
                dragBckColor = Color.FromArgb(Rb, Gb, Bb);
            }
            else
            {
                dragBckColor = frmColor;
            }

            alpha = 255;
            bckColor = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(alpha, dragBckColor));
        }
        else
        {
            bckColor = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(alpha, this.BackColor));
        }

        if (this.BackColor != Color.Transparent | drag)
        {
            g.FillRectangle(bckColor, bounds);
        }

        bckColor.Dispose();
        g.Dispose();
        base.OnPaint(e);
    }

    protected override void OnBackColorChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        if (this.Parent != null)
        {
            Parent.Invalidate(this.Bounds, true);
        }
        base.OnBackColorChanged(e);
    }

    protected override void OnParentBackColorChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        this.Invalidate();
        base.OnParentBackColorChanged(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: Worked nicely for me.

Comment: ppl just copy and paste in your custom class and change constructor name. works perfectly!! thank you

Comment: This currently has a serious bug.  In the OnPaint override, it is calling Dispose on the e.Graphics object, which should not be done.  The application is likely to crash if you dispose of the Graphics object that was passed in.  If you didn't create it, you shouldn't dispose of it.

Comment: Works nicely when "Control" was changed to "Panel".

Comment: @Amen Ayach:  The application will crash if i set SetStyle(ControlStyles.AllPaintingInWmPaint, true) to reduce flicker

Comment: How can i add TranspCtrl control on top of other controls. This control is always behind of other controls

Comment: @Dominota from designer right click it and click "Bring to Front", from code `transpCtrl1.BringToFront();`

Comment: @AmenAyach it works reliably only in designer. In runtime the transparent control keep redrawen by components that take some interaction, I did not find a way to keep it permanently on top.

Comment: @AntonínLejsek I tried to put couple controls (TextBox, ComboBox and Button) above the Transparent one and I interacted with those controls and still working, note: I was using .Net 4.5.2 on windows 10, not sure if those "conditions" have effects

Comment: Although this solution is good, its extremely silly to dispose of the graphics object, if you dont want system to paint you can simply remove the base.OnPaint(e) call from the code.
no need to dispose graphics.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to use `Opacity` property and set it to zero to make form invisible.

If you want to make a control Transparent, as you have tried in your example, See this article

[How to: Give Your Control a Transparent Background](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wk5b13s4%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

It say the code you have written, must be in constructor of the control. Hence, I guess, you will need to create a custom control derived from your `pnlSelectArea` 's type most probaably a button. In in that custom control's constructor you can write code to set its style and color.

Comment: I don't want to make the control invisible. I want to make its contents invisible so I can use it to mouse over different parts of the image and use it as a 'select tool'

Comment: Then set those content's Opacity.

Comment: Brother Mahepp no Opacity property in winforms just in WPF

Comment: It is available for Form in winforms as well. OP can use a borderless Form for his/her usage.

Comment: @AmenAyach http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.opacity.aspx

Comment: @Maheep your link proove that no opacity for each **"CONTROL"** just for forms level...any way, thanks for your effort.

Comment: I think that you have not read my updated answer. What I have suggested for control is same which you later posted as your implementation.

Comment: You should mention that this only exists for WPF

Answer (score 1):

Here is what worked for me with because the other solutions did not work.

This is with transparent UserControl added to ListView/TreeView Control Collection

I know it says ButtonRenderer but it should work for any controls.

In the UserControl:

```
protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    ButtonRenderer.DrawParentBackground(e.Graphics, this.ClientRectangle, this);
}
```

in the Parent control:

```
protected override void WndProc(ref Message m) 
{
    if(m.Msg == 0xF)
        foreach(Control c in this.Controls) { c.Invalidate(); c.Update(); }

    base.WndProc(ref m);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

great!!
I finally managed to draw transparent shapes.
I've added a virtual method

```
Draw(g);
```

right before

```
bckColor.Dispose();
g.Dispose();
base.OnPaint(e);
```

and at the end the declaration of the virtual method

```
protected virtual void Draw(Graphics g){ }
```

Now I can continue creating my own Transparent shapes, graphics etc ...

Comment: Have you ever putted your custom control on top of other controls?

Answer (score 0):

There is one simple workaround for this. You can create an image with a transparent background (PNG) and add it for the Image property of the icon. This works fine as information does not have much flexibility in styling. Sometime this might not be suitable for everyone. Remember this is **only a workaround.**

PS:
Add where ever the text on the image and keep blank for the text property.