# Advice on implementation for button which supports opacity

Tags: c#, winforms, button, implementation, opacity

I didn't find a way in C# for creating a button which will support opacity - instead of just appearing when show method is called, to have the ability to slowly fade it into view.

I created my own button and I would like to know what you think of the implementation.

Basically, **I created a Windows Form**, which supports opacity property and handled all the corner cases regarding "adding" a form to another form, specifically:
 - location changed event
 - the owner form lost focus

The form consist of a label, which represents the button's text and that's all.

**The form constructor** gets the text for the label, the desired size of the button and the speed (based on an Enum) for the button appear.
In **the form load method** the label is being located in the middle of the button

**when the label or the form itself clicked** a simple graphic is performed and an event is raised to whoever catches it.

My Code:

1. Created a Form - named buttonForm
2. Constructor

   ```
           InitializeComponent();
           this.Owner = owner;
           _buttonText = buttonText;
           _buttonSize = buttonSize;
           _usedSpeedOpacity = SelectSpeedOpacity(showSpeed);
   ```
3. A method to illustrate click command - being called when the user clicks on the form and on the label itself:

   ```
       this.Location = new Point(this.Location.X + 1, this.Location.Y);
       this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None;
       Thread.Sleep(50);
       this.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedToolWindow;
       this.Location = new Point(this.Location.X - 1, this.Location.Y);
       if (Button_Clicked != null)
       {
           Button_Clicked();
       }
   ```
4. form load - locating the label in the middle of the control etc

   ```
       labelButtonText.Text = _buttonText;
       this.Size = _buttonSize;
       double remainning = this.Width - labelButtonText.Size.Width;
       Point labelNewLocation = new Point(
           (int)(remainning / 2),
           (int)(this.Height / 2 - this.Font.Height / 2));
       labelButtonText.Location = labelNewLocation;
   ```
5. FadeShow (and FadeHide the same)

   ```
       int tempCounter = 0;
       Opacity = 0;
       Show();
       while (tempCounter <= 1000)
       {
           if (Opacity == 1.0)
           {
               break;
           }
           if (tempCounter % 10 == 0)
           {
               Opacity += _usedSpeedOpacity;
           }
           Refresh();
           tempCounter++;
       }
       this.Visible = true;
       this.BringToFront();
   ```
6. Update location method so when the parent form moves i call this method

   ```
       this.Location = new Point(
           this.Location.X - (ParentFormLocation.X - newLocation.X),
           this.Location.Y - (ParentFormLocation.Y - newLocation.Y));
       ParentFormLocation = newLocation;
   ```
7. An event of my button_click

Thanks in advance,

Oz.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358500/winforms-making-a-control-transparent/9359642#9359642

Comment: Nice one but its not exactly what i need if I understand right - this is a control which supports opacity and i need an opacity fade in and out control

Comment: Interesting method however I believe this would mean the current thread would be constantly busy, perhaps if you used a background worker you could report the progress back and then update opacity that way.  If you want I can post code

Comment: You mean that a background thread will paint the button?

Answer (score 0):

I did something similar with a windows form that changed its height.  The way I did it was to implement a timer within the code so every half a second the opacity changed.

While the below is not a 100% correct answer without your code its difficult to show you.

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {            
            if (btnName.Opacity < 100)
            {
                btnName.Opacity++;
                timer2.Stop();
                timer2.Interval = 5000;
                timer2.Start();
            } else {
                timer2.Stop();
           }
        }
```

Comment: Nice. Although i prefer less timers in my application, its better than opening a thread for that matter. What do you say about my implementation ?

Comment: Can you post the implementation code as I tend to understand code better :)