# Remove white background for radio button

Tags: c#, winforms, colors, radio-button

I have an application in which I have used radio button over an image so it seems very bad with white background in radio button.

[image]

So is there a way I can remove that white background ?

Comment: If you care about `UI` it may be worth to create a custom `RadioButton` which will also looks *fancy* (not as ugly as standard one). It can support transparency from the box.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only setting the `BackColor` to `Color.Transparent` is not enough to get rid of the little border that is around the `RadioButton`.

What you will need to also do is call the following code for each radio button to ensure that the background does actually go transparent

```
rbnTest.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
Point pos = this.PointToScreen(rbnTest.Location);
rbnTest.Parent = pibPicture;
rbnTest.Location = pibPicture.PointToClient(pos);
```

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14305950) (Not a true duplicate, but similar, hence not flaggin as duplicate)

I would recommend refactoring that code into a reusable method so that you do not scatter the code all over your project.

Answer (score 1):

Locate the constructor for your control class. The constructor appears in the control's code file. In C#, the constructor is the method with the same name as the control and with no return value.

Call the SetStyle method of your form in the constructor.

```
SetStyle(ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor, true);
```

add the following line. This will set your control's BackColor to Transparent.

```
this.BackColor = Color.Transparent;
```

**Note**
Windows Forms controls do not support true transparency. The background of a transparent Windows Forms control is painted by its parent.

Comment: FYI, I have tagged `Winform` so this is a `winform` application and not a website.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the `RadioButton.BackgroundImage` or the `RadioButton.BackColor` property. Choose the one that suits you best

Comment: Can you specify which `BackColor` I have to set to achieve this ?

Comment: A serious question? Maybe... purple for a skin-colored picture in the back? Have you tried setting transparent? If this isnt working, I would say you should guess the best color for yourself. Its your project.

Comment: Yeah. I agree, setting the background color to transparent seems to be your best option