# Message Box in Metro Style XP, W7 and W8

Tags: c#, winforms

Let's get straight to the point, a time'm implementing a Message Box in Metro Style with Windows Forms and C #
implementation was cool, but I'm having problems with semi transparent background on windows XP, use the method:

```
this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb (0x46, 0x69, 0x69, 0x69);
```

This model worked perfectly on windows 7 and 8 on XP but not also renders simply ignores the parameter Alpha. and beyond it depending on the system model theme he does not respond to Alpha too.

Even after searching I did not find something that really works perfectly in this Annex I developed a model based on other examples, to work on Windows XP, 7 and 8, the background is semi transparent independent of themes but does not render the controls inside the form of message simply ignores all content.

Hope you can give me a help.

Thank you in advance.

[Download Examples](http://sdrv.ms/18tQn3X)

Comment: Please take a look through [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [formatting help](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting). I tried editing your post, but I can't understand your true intention.

Comment: Ok,
  What I want and create a message box in Windows 8 Metro style but the semi transparent background is not compatible with versions of Windows XP, Windows 7 and Windows 8, the transparency is simply ignored, with the example model could reach a standard that maintains the appearance but it ignores the controls within the form.

See the examples in https://skydrive.live.com/?cid=2f562362cfabc8d2&id=2F562362CFABC8D2!25327&ithint=folder,&authkey=!ACU5a0_stdQSFE0

Answer (score 0):

Only Top-Level windows (Forms) support alpha transparence in Winforms, but not controls.
If you want to have semi-transparent controls in Winforms you'll have to implement that feature by yourself.

See this post as an example:
[Winforms: Making a control transparent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358500/winforms-making-a-control-transparent)

**Edit:**
If you want a transparent / semi-transparent MessageBox, you have to create it yourself. Simply inherit from `Form` (which supports transparency) and create the look and feel that you want to have. Then you can simply set the opacity of 'your' MessageBox:

```
myMessageBox.Opacity = .75;
```

If you want more control over the appearance of your controls you should consider using WPF. Here is a WPF-controll that seems to fit your needs:

[All-Purpose Message Box in WPF](http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/619333/All-Purpose-Message-Box-in-WPF)

Comment: Thank you,
  Not like semi-transparent controls, I would just like the bottom of the form semi-transparent as well as message boxes in windows 8.

Comment: See the examples in the link:

http://sdrv.ms/18tQn3X

Would the same result in windows XP, 7, 8

Comment: Regarding the messagebox I have edited my post. Simply create your own with inheriting from Form. But what do you mean with just the bottom of your form semi-transparent?

Comment: Yes only the background should be semi transparent, as in the example images.
thanks for attention.

Comment: You can see an example in (sdrv.ms/18tQn3X) check images and design style.

Comment: I think that would be easy with WPF but very very very tricky with Winforms. I can not think of any good solution.

Comment: I do not have experience in WPF, you think he will behave perfectly on windows XP?

Comment: WPF is much more flexible with control-configuration than Winforms. Take a look at this: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/619333/All-Purpose-Message-Box-in-WPF    This seem to be what you are looking for. You can also mix Winforms and WPF. But you have to google that yourself as I have no experience with mixing WPF and Winforms myself.

Comment: Ok thanks for the help, I will continue my fight to solve the problem.