# Overlapping User Controls in c#

Tags: winforms, transparency, opacity, overlapping

I want to overlap two user controls but with transparency. The best way to explain this is by referring to the image I have uploaded.

As you can see on the image, I have three user controls in my panel. I want to overlap onw control on top of the other control and it should be with a transparency value (0 to 1). Is there a way to do this?

In this link is the image I was talking about. A user Controls contains a label ("Name") and a bitmap. On the image there are three such controls.

P.S. Because of my low reputation Im not allowed to upload images so I just gave the link of the image.

[My User Controls](https://www.dropbox.com/s/tvy7elufmrsvm0g/UserControls.png)

Comment: Which operating system or programming framework? For example Windows,  WPF, ...?

Comment: The reason you can't embed the image is that it's PNG format.

Comment: .net and windows forms.

Comment: No I tried jpeg as well but it says that you should have a reputation over 10.

Comment: Maybe this answers your question: http://stackoverflow.com/a/9359642/49942

Comment: hmm Yes it seems like it is similar to my question. Anyway I will adapt that code to my issue somehow. Thnx for the link :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Winforms: Making a control transparent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358500/winforms-making-a-control-transparent)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're better off just merging the 3 images instead of the controls.

How to do that? Here's a link:

[Merging two images in C#/.NET](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/465172/merging-two-images-in-c-net)