# Fade to black and back

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a form that has a custom TabControl which it's tabs are invisible, so i can move to others tabs programmatically. However, I'm facing an issue. I want to slowly dim the current tab (when moving to a new one), and once it's completely black, move to the new tab, and then slowly make the black disappear so the new tab appears.

I thought about making a transparent picturebox color on the whole tab page (and on the second one), and then once moving, start a timer that sets it's back color to black and increases opacity from 0 to 100 (so it's turning black) - and then move to the new page, and reduce the opacity from 100 to 0. However, there's no opacity property in picturebox control. Is there a  workaround?

Comment: Why not use another form instead of picturebox. because forms have that property.

Comment: @WaqasShabbir I already mentioned I'm using a hidden tab control. I donj't want to start showing forms, it'll look unnatural.

Comment: forms with border style= none, and startup style = maximum, and having back color black... is not it looks liky a pic box.?

Comment: @WaqasShabbir But it would still look like unnatural (open form animation..)

Comment: when you move to next tab then the form on which your tab is present, can do this above mentioned task.

Comment: You can create a new control with an opacity property:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358500/winforms-making-a-control-transparent