# How to determine whether a control allows transparency in C#?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, winforms, transparency

Under Windows Forms technology, I'm subclassing the **Form** class and overriding the **OnControlAdded** event invocator, my intention is that every control that is added to the control collection of my form, set its `Control.BackColor` property to `Color.Transparent` value regardless of the default color inheritance when a control is added into my Form.

However, as you probably know, some controls such as `ListView` does not accept transparency and when attempting to set the `Color.Transparent` value, a `System.ArgumentException` will be thrown telling you can set transparent color.

Then, my question is:

In C# or VB.NET, which would be the proper way (maybe with Reflection, or maybe calling a Win32 function) to determine at runtime whether a control allows a transparent back color (`Color.Transparent`)?... instead of handling the specified exception or classifying the control types in a `switch` case, for example.

Comment: While this doesn't answer your question directly, it may contain something useful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9358500/making-a-control-transparent

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To check if a control supports `Transparent` back color, You can use [`GetStyle`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.getstyle%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) method of the control by passing [`ControlStyles.SupportsTransparentBackColor`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.controlstyles(v=vs.110).aspx) flag as input.

The result is a `bool` value which tells you if the controls supports the style.

> If `true`, the control accepts a `BackColor` with an alpha component of
>   less than 255 to simulate transparency. Transparency will be simulated
>   only if the UserPaint bit is set to true and the parent control is
>   derived from Control.

The method is protected so it's accessible in derived classes.

If you are going to use it from outside of a control, you need to call it by reflection:

```
public static bool GetControlStyle(Control control, ControlStyles flags)
{
    Type type = control.GetType();
    BindingFlags bindingFlags = BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance;
    MethodInfo method = type.GetMethod("GetStyle", bindingFlags);
    object[] param = { flags };
    return (bool)method.Invoke(control, param);
}
```